# R Code for ANOVA of data from plot sampling in RCBD

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model

I set up a RCBD experiment in which I evaluated some maize varieties or treatments (V) in replicated blocks(R). I however also sampled (S) 5 plants from each varietal plot. I intend to write a code with R that would include each of the sources of variation (SOV) as shown in the attached image below. My main challenge is with the sampling error(S) which is nested within replicates (R) and varieties (V). I think the S is a random effect while V and R are fixed effects(?)
I have tried
aov(yield~R+V+S/R/V, data) and even 
lmer(yield~R+V+R(1|S), data 
but didn't get me the correct degrees of freedom for each SOV (based on my manual calculations). Kindly help! [image]